# unable to launch android application due to "Activity class does not exist" error

Tags: android, manifest

I am a newbie to android development trying to make an app(calculator) but am unable to launch the application due to the following error:

```
Error while executing: am start -n "apper.com.calc1/apper.com.calc1.StartActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=apper.com.calc1/.StartActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {apper.com.calc1/apper.com.calc1.StartActivity} does not exist.
Error while Launching activity
```

And here is Android manifest file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="apper.com.calc1">

<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_calculator"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:theme="@style/CalculatorTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".StartActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_CALCULATOR" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".CalculatorL"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />

</application>
```

StartActivity.java

```
package com.apper.calc1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class StartActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (Utils.hasLollipop()) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, CalculatorL.class));
    } else {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, CalculatorGB.class));
    }
    finish();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried `package="com.apper.calc1"` instead of `package="apper.com.calc1"` ?

Comment: try cleaning the project and build it again.

Answer (score 0):

in your manifest the package is:

```
package="apper.com.calc1"
```

but in your StartActivity is:

```
package com.apper.calc1;
```

try to modify it

Answer (score 0):

Log cat Error says there is no `apper.com.calc1.StartActivity` in your project which is true. What you have is `com.apper.calc1.StartActivity`.

Try changing the package name in the manifest to `com.apper.calc1` like Mike mentioned or revert the changes you've made earlier with the package name.